# A Tale of Two UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

So I think I'm going crazy.

I've updated to XCode 4.2 so I'd have the IOS 5 SDK.

I have an app that's been working great until the upgrade. Now, I have a strange problem. It does not work on my IOS 5 iPad 2, nor will it work in the IOS 5 simulator. Works fine in the 4.3 simulator.

For the purposes of this question, I have two classes based on UIViewController. They do not use NIB files. One, called HistoryBrowser, works great. The other, NoteBrowseViewController, constructed along the same lines, does not.

From NoteBrowseView.Controller.h:

```
@interface NoteBrowseViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate,        UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITabBarDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {
  UITableView* tableView;
  ... buncha other vars ...
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITableView* tableView;
... buncha other properties ...
```

From NoteBrowseViewController.m:

```
@synthesize tableView

- (id)initWithEditing:(BOOL)inEditingMode inserting:(BOOL)inserting {
self=[super init];
if (self) {
    self.isInserting=inserting;
    self.isEditing=inEditingMode;
    self.viewIsMap=NO;
    self.insertType=defInsertTypeLink;

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"viewSortOrder",
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],@"priorityView",
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],@"simpleView",
                                 nil];

    [defaults registerDefaults:appDefaults];

    self.viewIsSimple=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"simpleView"];
}
return self;
}

-(void)loadView {
self.view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

UIButton* aButton;
UIImage* buttonImage;
UIBarButtonItem* spacer=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UISegmentedControl* sc=[[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alpha",@"Edit", @"View", nil]];
[sc addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[sc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[sc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[sc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:2];
sc.selectedSegmentIndex=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"viewSortOrder"];
sc.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

UISegmentedControl* prisc=[[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Open",@"All", nil]];
[prisc addTarget:self action:@selector(prioritySegmentedControlValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[prisc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[prisc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
prisc.selectedSegmentIndex=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"priorityView"];
prisc.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;

UIBarButtonItem* segmentedButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:sc];
UIBarButtonItem* prioritySegmentedButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:prisc];

buttonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"13-plus.png"];
aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem* addButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"187-pencil.png"];
aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem* editButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"21-circle-east.png"];
aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem* simplify=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(simplify:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"25-circle-west.png"];
aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem* complexify=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(complexify:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"243-globe.png"];
aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem* map=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mapify:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

buttonImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"162-receipt.png"];
aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
UIBarButtonItem* notes=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:aButton];
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showNotes:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem* cancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
self.doneToolbar=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, cancelButton, nil];

self.toolbar=[[[UIToolbar alloc]init]autorelease];

if(self.isEditing) {
    self.complexToolbar=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:simplify, spacer, segmentedButton, prioritySegmentedButton, spacer, cancelButton, nil];
    self.simpleToolbar=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:complexify, spacer, cancelButton, nil];
}
else {
    self.complexToolbar=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:simplify, map, spacer, segmentedButton, prioritySegmentedButton, spacer, addButton, editButton, cancelButton, nil];
    self.simpleToolbar=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:complexify, map, spacer, addButton, editButton, cancelButton, nil];
}
self.mapToolbar=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:notes, spacer, prioritySegmentedButton, spacer, cancelButton, nil];

if (self.viewIsSimple) {
    [self.toolbar setItems:self.simpleToolbar animated:YES];
}
else {
    [self.toolbar setItems:self.complexToolbar animated:YES];
}

self.toolbar.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;        
[self.toolbar sizeToFit];

CGFloat toolbarHeight = [self.toolbar frame].size.height;
CGRect rootViewBounds=self.view.bounds;
CGFloat rootViewHeight = CGRectGetHeight(rootViewBounds);
CGFloat rootViewWidth = CGRectGetWidth(rootViewBounds);
[self.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, rootViewWidth, toolbarHeight)];

self.mapView=[[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, rootViewHeight-(self.isInserting?49:0)-toolbarHeight)]autorelease];
self.mapView.delegate=self;
self.mapView.zoomEnabled=YES;
self.mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
self.mapView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolbarHeight, rootViewWidth, rootViewHeight-(self.isInserting?49:0)-toolbarHeight) 
                                           style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.delegate=self;
self.tableView.dataSource=self;
self.tableView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES; 
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

UISearchBar* searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, rootViewWidth, 44.0)];
searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

self.searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
[self.view addSubview:self.toolbar];

if (self.isInserting) {
    UITabBarItem* item1=[[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Link" image:nil tag:defInsertTypeLink]autorelease];
    UITabBarItem* item2=[[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Contents Later" image:nil tag:defInsertTypeContentsLater]autorelease];
    UITabBarItem* item3=[[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Contents Now" image:nil tag:defInsertTypeContentsNow]autorelease];
    UITabBar* tabbar=[[UITabBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, rootViewHeight-49, rootViewWidth, 49)];
    tabbar.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [tabbar setDelegate:self];
    [tabbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, item2, item3, nil] animated:YES];
    [tabbar setSelectedItem:item1];
    [self.view addSubview:tabbar];
}

if(self.viewIsSimple) {
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(200.0, 625.0);         
}
else {
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(450.0, 625.0); 
}
self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES; 
self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.note=nil;

[sc release];
[prisc release];
[addButton release];
[prioritySegmentedButton release];
[cancelButton release];
[segmentedButton release];
[spacer release];
[editButton release];
[map release];
[simplify release];
[complexify release];
}
```

And finally, the a NoteBrowseViewController is instantiated thusly from another view controller:

```
self.noteBrowseViewController=[[NoteBrowseViewController alloc]initWithEditing:NO inserting:NO];
self.noteBrowseViewController.delegate=self;
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:self.noteBrowseViewController];
self.popoverController.delegate = self;
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton*)sender).frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

So this is what happens. If I run this in debug, and follow along, as soon as execution gets to this line:

```
CGRect rootViewBounds=self.view.bounds;
```

The program crashes with the following errors:

```
2011-10-20 11:42:02.703 ActionNote3[12332:15803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]:  object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1eb0052 0x2a60d0a 0x1e9d36e 0x1e9e220 0x1968cb6 0x5153b 0x50e11 0x50879 0x52e4a 0xdcc64e 0x4bcb3 0x72d1 0x1eb1ec9 0xd095c2 0xd0955a 0xdaeb76 0xdaf03f 0xdae2fe 0xd2ea30 0xd2ec56 0xd15384 0xd08aa9 0x20c7fa9 0x1e841c5 0x1de9022 0x1de790a 0x1de6db4 0x1de6ccb 0x20c6879 0x20c693e 0xd06a9b 0x2dbd 0x2d35)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

By watching things during the debug, I know self.view is being set up properly, and that loadView is being called when it should be. And it's not this line that makes it fail - it's anything that refers to self.view! what???

What really makes me crazy is that I have another subclassed view controller, HistoryBrowser, that is loaded in exactly the same manner... and it works fine.

So, aside from being upset that I cannot figure this out, i'd like to understand:

1. What's changed in XCode 4.2 (from 4.1) that would cause this, or is
   this an IOS 5 issue?
2. What does this error mean, and what can I do
   about it?

**EDIT:**

So based on suggestions from Abberant's answer below, I:

1. changed the initwithnib to just be init
2. removed the loadView method
3. added the full error message
4. added more relevant code to the init method

And now, referencing self.view works properly. But things have just gotten stranger.

Execution makes it past the first reference to self.view without error. However, it now halts at:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

in the init method.

The error message received is eerily similar to the one I was receiving before:

```
2011-10-20 12:34:04.818 ActionNote3[13487:15803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1eaf052 0x2a5fd0a 0x1e9c36e 0x1e9d220 0x1967cb6 0x50b4b 0x50421 0x4fe89 0x4d757 0x6641 0x1eb0ec9 0xd085c2 0xd0855a 0xdadb76 0xdae03f 0xdad2fe 0xd2da30 0xd2dc56 0xd14384 0xd07aa9 0x20c6fa9 0x1e831c5 0x1de8022 0x1de690a 0x1de5db4 0x1de5ccb 0x20c5879 0x20c593e 0xd05a9b 0x212d 0x20a5)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

So, if I comment that line out, execution procedes until it reaches this group of lines, where it fails when it attempts to do the performFetch.

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self currentFetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

Debugging into the code for [self currentFetchedResultsController] shows that the fetched results controller is being set up properly and without issue.

The error received here is the same as above. The numbers in the first throw call stack change, but otherwise the error is the same.

So I'm left thinking that I have a larger problem going on here. I just have no idea how to track it down. As I said way up there somewhere, I have another view, constructed in the same manner, that loads fine.

**Edit:**

So NJones in his answer below suggested following Apple's guidelines by placing the appropriate code in loadView and viewDidLoad. So I did. I moved all view construction out of init and into loadView, and fired up the fetchedResultsController in viewDidLoad.

The app still crashes in the same spot:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
```

With the same error as noted above.

Thanks!

Comment: First off I love any question that starts with "So I think I'm going crazy."  Try putting this line of code before the "CGRect roo..." line:   NSLog(@"view is properly set? %@",([self.view isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]])?@"YES":@"NO"); Sorry, this isn't an answer, and I can't format for code in a comment.

Comment: The reason for the crash is apparently this: "[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil", but you gave us no code that uses insertObject:atIndex:, so we can't see what the nil object is. By the way, if you're not using any NIB files and not calling the super initWithNibName:, why use initWithNibName and not just init?

Comment: @Aberrant, I have NO code that does that. If i did, i would agree with your assesment. Perhaps theres internal code generated by apple that i cannot see that does, but its not ky code  I used to use nibs, but got rid of them. You'll note that when I call [super init] I just call init.

Comment: @Njones - Since this line becomes the first reference to self.view, it results in a call to loadView, which sets the view as it should. Upon return, the app crashes on that line - the NSLog line that you suggested. I really have no idea why it would crash on first reference to self.view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the answer, and it's not something anyone would have guessed without seeing a lot more code. But, hopefully this answer will help other people who might run into the same thing.

In what has become my loadView method (but was originally in my init method, and still is in the code above), I had the following lines:

```
UISegmentedControl* sc=[[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alpha",@"Edit", @"View", nil]];
[sc addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[sc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[sc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:1];
[sc setWidth:55.0 forSegmentAtIndex:2];
sc.selectedSegmentIndex=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"viewSortOrder"];
sc.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
```

segmentedControlValueChanged: would set a string var (and store the index of the selected button in user defaults). The string var was later used to determine sort order when firing up  my fetchedresultscontroller.

Prior to IOS 5, when I set sc.selectedSegmentIndex, the method identified in the selector would get fired, and everything would get set up properly. In IOS 5, this is no longer the case, and the string var (setting a sort order) would not get set.

What's interesting is that upon execution this line:

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

would cause the fetchedReultsController to be accessed and, by accessing it, it would be initialized. When it went to be initialized, it would set the sort order and include a null value for the field name, hence the error message, which now makes sense.

**So the root cause of the problem was that prior to IOS 5, setting the selectedSegmentIndex on a UISegmentedControl would fire the action associated with the control. Starting with IOS 5, this is no longer the case.**

The original cause of the problem, which several people helped me resolve, was that I was not following the viewController load process properly. I am not using NIB files. Apple says that if you dont use a nib file, you have to define loadView to set up the view. If loadView is not defined, self.view is set internally, and viewDidLoad is called. The reason the app crashed at the first reference of self.view, then, is that I had logic in viewDidLoad to set up the fetchedResultsController. When I moved the view setup logic into loadView, references to self.view no longer started up the fetchedresultscontroller.

Comment: Nice. I'm glad you finally found your problem. That makes sense in context. Believe it or not I was still curious about this today. And trying to implement some of your load view method to see what was going on. If you don't mind me asking how did you manage to set your self.searchDisplayController? According to the UIViewController superclass this is a readonly property. Did you implement setSearchDisplayController in your subclass or am I missing something?

Comment: I really appreciate all the help you gave me. Thank you. I did not implement setSearchDisplayController in my code. I didn't know it was read only, but the docs go on to say: "This property reflects the value of the searchDisplayController outlet that you set in Interface Builder. If you create your search display controller programmatically, this property is set automatically by the search display controller when it is initialized." I dont have time to test it right now, but I wonder what would happen if I commented out the assignment line.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you should use the loading model apple suggests. This is some of the code generated in xCode when you create a new UIViewController subclass (abridged to fit):

```
/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
-(void)loadView{
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/
```

Based on just this, Since you are creating your view programmatically, I would say that most of what you have in your init method belongs in the loadView method.

Comment: I thought that might be worth doing, so I did. I moved all the code out of init except some var settings, and put it all in loadView. When I get to this line: self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar, it crashes with the same error.

Comment: @Chris, can you please post your call stack.

Comment: unless I misunderstand, I did that as part of the error message above. It's that string of hex numbers. Is there a way to resolve that into something human-readable?

Comment: My call stack is by default partly human readable (Symbolicated). I don't know that I did anything to make it that way. Are you on a device or simulator?

Comment: I'm using the IOS 5 simulator.

Comment: @Chris, I had never noticed, since I don't use my 5.0 simulator often, but, mine is not symobolicating on 5.0 either. Have you tried using the 4.3 iPad simulator?

Comment: And yes, it works great in the 4.3 simulator. I wouldn't worry so much about the 5.0 simulator, but it also doesn't work on my 5.0 ipad.

Comment: I just tried crashing an app on my iPad1 running 5.0 and it also gave me useless hex garbage, very annoying, but a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Been thinking about and looking for information on this for a while, but it might be any number of things. Perhaps the self.view gets called before the loadView somewhere, maybe it's because initWithNibName triggers something you don't want, maybe it's because your view is smaller than the screen/window, which is not advised, maybe the new iOS has a bug in it... With so little of your code, no way to debug and an incomplete error message, I can't see what causes it.

However, I might have a workaround:

How about removing that loadView override so that the viewController makes its own view, then add your mainView to that default view?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It got me past the first reference to self.view without issue. However, I get the same error further down when I try to add a search bar to a table view. If I comment that out, I get the same message again when I attempt to do a performFetch on a fetchedresultscontroller. Something larger is going on.. I just dont have a clue what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says you are adding a nil to an array. I'm think tableViewHeader could be considered an objectAtIndex:0 since it's the first of an array of rows.  Try putting this line above it :

```
NSLog(@"searchBar = %@",searchBar;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Edit(1):
Then try these:

```
NSLog(@"self = %@",self);
NSLog(@"self.tableView = %@",self.tableView);
NSLog(@"self.tableView.tableHeaderView = %@",self.tableView.tableHeaderView);
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

Edit(2):

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setTableHeaderView:)]){
    NSLog(@"tableView does respond");
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
}
```

I don't think this will fix the problem, but it should help hunt down the problem.

Comment: I've done that, and searchBar is valid at that point. thanks.

Comment: Everything returned what it should: 2011-10-20 20:08:53.389 ActionNote3[17031:15803] self = <NoteBrowseViewController: 0x81d8f50>
2011-10-20 20:08:54.742 ActionNote3[17031:15803] self.tableView = <UITableView: 0x888d800; frame = (0 44; 768 960); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x81e43e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
2011-10-20 20:08:57.028 ActionNote3[17031:15803] self.tableView.tableHeaderView = (null)
Upon execution of the assignment, the same error message came up. According to the docs, tableHeaderView defaults to nil. Most annoying!

Comment: Unfortunately, yes that is what I was afraid it would say; Since that is what it should say. I edited again. Oh and on the call stack being unreadable, that is a bug that has been reported to apple.

Comment: Yeah... So it does respond to the selector, and does NOT like being set to nil. Same error. Thank you for all of your help so far!

Comment: @Chris; Since you are right about the callback functions. The only thing I can think of is that some logic somewhere is not liking your searchBar and is interrupting the assignment. Some dumb nit-picky iOS5 problem. I'd Try creating the searchBar with just [[UISearchBar alloc] init]. You have it set to resize anyway. That would rule out it checking the frame size.